# Are there specific advantages to using Express over PHP for a React frontend client needing a proxy server for oauth2?

Tags: php, reactjs, express

I have a website that is PHP based with a react bundle to render the UI within the `<body>` of the php page (using JSON supplied from the PHP side).

Within this setup, some of the PHP pages have custom React APP that need to make axios calls using OAuth2 protocol (code grant).

Since I can't keep secrets in the react client side axios calls, the options (from researching online) is to use a proxy server via Express.

Are there specific benefits to using Express as the proxy server for a React Client or is a PHP proxy also kosher within this setup?

PHP Proxy method:

PHP page: React APP axios -> PHP proxy -> API Auth Server

VS

Express proxy method:

PHP page: React APP axios -> Express Proxy -> API Auth Server

Comment: There is no difference whether you use a JavaScript, PHP, Python, Java or C++ based backend/proxy.

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks for the input. I wasn't sure whether react client side had magic methods into secrets on the server side (since they are in the same repo), but it seems like the only communication between react client and express server is via http. So it makes sense that it doesn't really matter what tech is used for the proxy.